# unresolved external symbol with FTD3XX.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc, ftdi

Using VS2005 on an MFC project, I can't make any function call to FTD3XX.dll by using the lib FTDI provided (USB to Serial)

Imported the FTD3XX.h file and added the FTD3XX.lib to Additional dependencies under Linker > Input.

None of the calls will work, for example:
    **FT_STATUS status;

    DWORD dwNumDevs;

    status = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&dwNumDevs);**

It keeps failing on unresolved external symbol meaning I did not import the DLL properly.

What am I missing here ?
Thank you

Comment: Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories? (not sure about exact path in VS-2005)

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: The error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1(void)" (?OnBnClickedButton1@CMFCApplication2Dlg@@QAEXXZ) MFCApplication2 c:\Users\yyakov\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MFCApplication2\MFCApplication2\MFCApplication2Dlg.obj 1

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using another .lib file.

It is possible that the DLL I tries to use was compiled on an older VS.

Comment: The library comes with both 32- and 64-bit .lib files.  Likely picked the wrong one at first.